# How to maintain request.getReader() with a filter?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, request, servlet-filters

After I added a filter to my app, I am not able to read anything from `HttpServletRequest.getReader()` in my controllers.

I am calling request.getParameter() a few times, but other than that my filter doesn't do much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I just thought through the problem and realized that for POST requests, calling getParameter() can cause a problem because POST params would typically be in the request body. The input stream will indeed be opened implicitly by the filter.

In my filter (and in my case) I need to check:

```
if (((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod().equals("GET")) {...}
```